MSK with SASL/SCRAM authentication. I can access the cluster but cant perform any action
We're currently building an MSK cluster. We use 2 types of authentication for 2 different clients.
The IAM authentication works fine.
But for the SASL/SCRAM authentication that it's not the case, we created a secret for username/password connection and linked it to the MSK cluster.
Using our client or with a UI client for windows it's the same issue we have a connection but with limited functionalities (like creating a topic or reading one).
Please take a look at the error the UI clients returns :

Could not complete DescribeConfigs action: you can try to continue with limited functionality. ClusterAuthorizationException: Cluster authorization failed. Make sure that your user has all access rights (DescribeConsumerGroups, DescribeCluster, DescribeConfigs) for full functionality.

Also take a look at our AWS secret policy JSON file :
  {
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Sid" : "......",
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
      "Service" : "kafka.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action" : "secretsmanager:getSecretValue",
    "Resource" : "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-3...............Z"
  } ]
}

Do we need to modify the ACLs policies directly on the Kafka instance ? How?

You have to set allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found to true in order to access the cluster without ACLs.
If you need to set it to false, you can list current ACLs, and add new ones using the list-acls.sh command in Kafka CLI:
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/content/kafka-tools-kafka-acls.html
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz

Thanks for your answer. Actually we need to set it to false. But I dont know fow to access the Kafka CLI via AWS. SSH is disable (or just simply dont know how) any idea?

did you enable public access to Kafka cluster? or is it running in private subnets?

@EdbE its prublic

@sidyag, if the cluster is public, you cannot change allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found to true

It seems like you've changed allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found to false.
If that's the case, then you won't have access with SCRAM auth method until you enable ACLs. So, you need to run kafka-acls command and add permissions to the user you use to read topics, or write...
For example, you will need to use a user that already has permissions to set up ACLs, alternatively, you can use unauthenticated method, or zookeeper instead of bootstrap servers, so authentication is not checked:
kafka/bin/kafka-acls.sh --bootstrap-server msk:9096 \
  --command-config adminclient-configs.conf \
  --add \
  --allow-principal User:boris \
  --allow-principal User:ed \
  --operation read \
  --operation write \
  --topic my-topic


Thanks ! What do you have in adminclient-configs.conf ? We currently have IAM config.
Also  kafka/bin/kafka-acls.sh where do you access this? Seems like I don't have access to it
